# ng-src not fixed by imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a Firefox addon. I have a very simple code:

```
var ANG_APP = angular.module('zooniversexpert', [])
    .config(['$compileProvider', function( $compileProvider ) {
            $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|http?):/);
        }
    ])
    .controller('BodyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        this.gallery = [{url:'http://zooniverse-export.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/21484_1000_D35_Season%202_Set%201_EK006076.JPG'}];
    }]);
```

That `gallery` array holds a single element with key `url` of `http://zooniverse-export.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/21484_1000_D35_Season%202_Set%201_EK006076.JPG`.

My HTML is here:

```
<body ng-controller="BodyController as BC">
    <img ng-src="aEntry.url" ng-repeat="aEntry in BC.gallery"/>
</body>
```

However the image fails to load, it keeps giving this error:

[image: Screenshot]

And inspection on the document shows this is what Angular tried to load:

```
<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-src="aEntry.url" ng-repeat="aEntry in BC.gallery" class="ng-scope" src="unsafe:aEntry.url" />
```

Please notice the `unsafe:aEntry.url`.

Comment: You should declare the `ng-src` like this `ng-src="{{aEntry.url}}"`.

Comment: Rawrrrr!! O my gosh, lol thanks.